# Chef_client with Vagrant where is "validation.pem"

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to setup chef server and client in my local box using Vagrant. 
  I've setup chef server using https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-server. The problem I am facing is I can't find  "validation.pem" file in "/etc/chef", I ran "knife configure -i" (also with --validation-key) but the dir is empty in chef-server.
  I need this validation.pem file for "vagrant up clients" to be passed using Vagrantfile's *chef.validation_key_path = "validation.pem"* config.
  I did workaround this by a. set up chef server b. create another centos vm c. knife bootstrap from server to this centos vm. I find /etc/chef/validation.pem. copy to dir where Vagrantfile is and further nodes gets provisioned with "vagrant up".
  Any ideas how to create validation.pem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file from `/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem` on the chef server.